# Create cordova plugin by accessing the xaml pages?

Tags: c#, cordova, xaml, windows-8.1, cordova-plugins

I have created a windows 8.1 sample project uisng c# & XAML. I want conumse this xaml pages in HTML cordova application.

Can access this c# code and also the controls in xaml pages by creating cordova plugin so that i can use this cordova plugin in my HTML project.

If this is not possible is there any other way to access this UI elements from xaml and C# functionlity in my HTML Cordova application?